# Control multiple objects with armature while maintaining individual origins?

Tags: animation, armature, gltf

I'm hoping to use a single bone to control the scale/rotation of many cubes, while using their individual origins as a pivot point. The reason for this is that I need to export as a small GLTF, and most other animation options are not feasible due to file limitations (or file size).

This is what is happening currently. The bone maintains itself as the pivot point no matter what:
[image]

And here is the effect I would like to recreate:

[image]

Is this possible?

(Baking, shape keys/morph targets, transformation drivers are not possible due to the amount of cubes I'm hoping to control - a realised instance of particles where I've separated the individual meshes into 5 groups and hope to control with 5 bones with slightly different parameters. If you think I'm missing something with these other processes, please let me know.)

Comment: You could just use a "Copy Transforms" constraint for the cubes. You just have to set the "Target" to "Local Space (Owner Orientation)". This should work just fine. But you'll have to copy the constraint to all the cubes and parent them as objects to the bone so that they'll move with the bone in object mode (if you want that). Unless you want to parent the object to the bone with automatic weights. Please provide the blend file so we can further help: [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, though this doesn't seem to work. When setting the target, the cubes are moved to the location of the armature, resulting in this: 

![Here](https://i.imgur.com/mLOVE6G.png)

And trying other settings, all cubes are rotated around their bounding box center rather than individual origins.

The blend file example is just two cubes and an armature to illustrate the issue, but here you go :)

[Blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qWVrRr27/)

Comment: My bad, it's not supposed to be copy transforms. It can be copy transforms but "Copy Rotation" will do it better and it's the same time set up: Set the target to "Local Space (Owner Orientation)". The results are shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkpxE.png). I just changed the bone display object to a cube so you can actually see its rotation properly and I also turned on all origins so you can see them. On the side panel is the setting for the modifier in one of the cubes. I'm happy to help :)

Comment: Ah, yeah this now works :) however, because we're just applying object constraints, the animation does not work when exporting to GLTF. I'm hoping to get a similar effect using "pose mode" so that the animation is exportable.

Seems like I will have to keep exploring. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Alright, but just to clarify, the cubes rotate when you rotate the bone in "Pose Mode". They don't do anything if you move or rotate the bone in object mode. Here's the files so you can check it out: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=RoD7dNQa" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/RoD7dNQa/)

Comment: @e3_productions The problem with your example is not _Object/Pose Mode_, but the constraint. LURO is asking for it to be working in glTF, but you cannot export the constraint to glTF. So if you pose something there, the objects have no constraints to pick up the pose.

Comment: Ohh. I see. I'm a bit unfamiliar with gITF. My bad

Comment: @e3_productions I do not know glTF either, but this comment "_because we're just applying object constraints, the animation does not work when exporting to GLTF_" was a good hint on that ;)